# Acrobat adobe can not open pdf file generated by gnuplot

Tags: pdf, gnuplot

I plot my data by gnuplot, then set output as pdf file.
When I use adobe to open such pdf file, it shows this error:

```
Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'Compare_E.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).
```

Here is the plot file I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set encoding iso_8859_1
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font "Helvetica" 14
set output "Da.pdf"
set xr[0:1000]
set yr[0:]
set xlabel "Time (ps)"
set ylabel "Da(\305^{2})"
set key left top

plot "800/data.dat" u ($1/1000):5 w line lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "green" title "800"
```

I found available term:

```
gnuplot> show terminal

   terminal type is x11 

gnuplot> set term

Available terminal types:
           canvas  HTML Canvas object
              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
          context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
          domterm  DomTerm terminal emulator with embedded SVG
             dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
              emf  Enhanced Metafile format
         epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
              fig  FIG graphics language V3.2 for XFIG graphics editor
             hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
               mf  Metafont plotting standard
               mp  MetaPost plotting standard
             pcl5  PCL5e/PCL5c printers using HP-GL/2
           pict2e  LaTeX2e picture environment
       postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
          pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
            pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
         pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
              svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics
          tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators
          tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals
          texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
         tkcanvas  Tk canvas widget
          unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
            vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator
              x11  X11 Window System interactive terminal
             xlib  X11 Window System (dump of gnuplot_x11 command stream)
            xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
gnuplot>
```

Is there anyone dealing with the same error?

Comment: Can you provide the file?

Comment: How exactly did you create this PDF? What was your terminal? Please show the (minimized) script or try the same procedure with a simple `plot x`. What is the file size of that specific file?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I provided more information in my question. I set the postscript terminal.

Comment: @BinhThien What is your gnuplot version and operating system? I am wondering why there is no PDF terminal.

Comment: this is gnuplot 5.4 installed in CentOS.

Comment: @BinhThien Hi, could you solve this?